# What could be causing a P0013 engine code to turn on and off on a 2.4L Ecotec in 2014 Buick Verano?

Tags: engine, cel, buick, gm, ecotec

Recently, my 2014 Buick Verano's (2.4L Ecotec engine) check engine light came on. It would turn on and off seemingly randomly though between engine starts.

I took it to a retail auto parts chain to get it scanned, and the code was **P0013** "Variable Valve Timing".  Some additional research pointed to two sensors on the top of the engine that should be replaced.  These are the sensors as seen on the engine (wires disconnected):

[image: sensors]

So I bought some replacement sensors and installed them *while the check engine light was on*.  After doing so, the check engine light was no longer on.  However, some days later, the light came back on.

Assuming the replacement parts aren't also defective, what else can I try to troubleshoot this?  I also heard I may need the code to be wiped out of the computer, however I was under the impression that so long as whatever the issue was that was causing the code was corrected, it should automatically turn the light off and keep it off.

Comment: Did you replace the SENSOR or the ACTUATOR?  There is one of each.

Comment: @jwh20 I replaced what's in the image (the parts in the top right look identical to what I purchased).  From what I understand, they are solenoids.

Comment: So that's the actuator.  Your next step is to check and replace the sensor(s).

Comment: Are you using the correct weight of oil?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 for it's last oil change not that long ago, I wasn't the one who performed it (a shop did).  So I'm not sure what was used, but I imagine they used the correct oil... hopefully.  I do remember them saying it was expensive due to oil prices now a days and the specific type of oil this engine needs apparently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the sensor.  See this video:

[Sensor replace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lm6bdt4Aijs)

He's showing the location of the sensor on the back of the engine here:

[image: Sensor location]

Comment: I'll have to give that a go.  Looks like another cheap part so thats good!

Comment: This, in essence, is a "link only answer". Consider bringing the information here which is in the video, but keeping the link to the video as your source of information. Links become stale or get changed. If that happens, there is no information here to help the next person.